# In Rails friendly_id how to use multiple attributes for the slug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I need to generate the slug with multiple attributes. For example, I need the `title` and the `id` both in every record (Not only in the ones with duplicate titles). So it will look like this : `hello-world-8943`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accoriding to [`docs`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId/Slugged), you can define your own `slug` structure as follows:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  friendly_id :uniqueslug, use: :slugged

  def uniqueslug
    "#{title}-#{id}"
  end

end
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! An edit for the first line : `friendly_id :uniqueslug, use: :slugged`, used slugged

Answer (score 0):

Put in your model

```
def to_param
   "#{title.parameterize}-#{id}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass your own slug:

That for example generates a random string.

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :random_slug, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  def random_slug
    self.slug = SecureRandom.hex(5)
  end
```